# Random.randint input

Tags: python, random, integer, generator

I want the user to be able to input the least number possible and the greatest number possible and for the `random.randint` function to print a random number in between the numbers entered.

But the `random.randint` will only use integers in the parentheses.
This is what I tried to use:

```
random.randint('Lnumber','Gnumber')
(input() == Lnumber (orGnumber))
```

of course, it comes up with an error.

how do I make python recognize the integer stored inside the variable(s) `Lnumber` and `Gnumber` and use them in `random.randint`?

Comment: maybe casting in int will help => (`int(Lnumber)`)

Comment: Did you really mean 'Lnumber' is your parameter? That's a literal string 'Lnumber' - not a variable.

Comment: @boatofturtles:  you're not using `variables`, you're using strings.  Lose the quotes.

Comment: sorry guys. Im kind of a newbie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way is to take the input and use randrange to generate the number:

```
mn, mx = map(int, input("Enter a min and max number separated by a space").split())
print (random.randrange(mn,mx))
```

Take the user input to get the `min` and `max` for the `range`, cast to `ints` using `map`:

```
mn, mx = map(int, input("Enter a min and max number separated by a space").split())
```

`print (random.randrange(mn,mx))` will print a number in the range of `min to max`

In your code:
    random.randint('Lnumber','Gnumber')

you are passing `strings` to `randint`, not variables.
 You would need to take input as above or set the variables to a value then pass the variables cast as `ints` to `randint`:

```
Lnumber = int(input("Enter a min"))
Gnumber = int(input("Enter a max"))
random.randint(Lnumber,Gnumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is store an input to a variable and then take that variable and pass it into the random.randint() command.

```
import random

firstNumber = int(input('Enter Your Min number')
secondNumber = int(input('enter Your Max number')
```

You can then either store the random number with a variable

```
thirdNumber = random.randint(firstNumber,secondNumber)
```